# Override object definition in a child and use it in parent

Tags: vb.net, object, parent

I have an object (called *Ticker*) that is defined in a parent class (*CoreEngine*), which I am trying to over-ride with a different object definition (but keep same name to use in *CoreEngine*) in one of the parent class's children. I think I'm supposed to use the 'Shadows' definition but I seem to be setting the object to null.

The ticker object is one that I want to use with methods defined in the parent class, but I want to change its type when defining a child of CoreEngine to use a different ticker object definition.

```
Public Class CoreEngine

    Public WithEvents Ticker As TickerClass

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub Activate()

        Ticker = New TickerClass()

    End Sub

''call methods that use Ticker

End Class
```

And in the child class:

```
Public Class ChildEngineClass
    Inherits CoreEngine

    Public Shadows WithEvents Ticker As BacktestTickerClass ' <<-- this class inherit the TickerClass too

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Activate()

        Ticker = New BacktestTickerClass() 

    End Sub

End Class
```

Overriding the Activate() method seems to work but when 'Ticker' is then referenced in the parent object's method it has a null reference. So my question is what am I doing wrong? how can i override the Ticker object in defined in the parent to reference a different object (which is also a child of the Ticker class) and still be able to use it in the parent object CoreEngine?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you cannot change the type of the field in the type class and expect the parent to know about it. Parent doesn't know anything about its children and doesn't know that you changed the type.

Since `BacktestTickerClass` inherits from `TickerClass`, what you can do is not change the definition of `Ticker` but still override `Activate` and instantiate it as the child class:

```
Public Class ChildEngineClass
    Inherits CoreEngine

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Activate()

        Ticker = New BacktestTickerClass() 

    End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously, this way you can only use methods that are available to `TickerClass` in your parent class. If you need to use anything that is available only in `BacktestTickerClass`, you have to override a method from parent in `ChildEngineClass`.

Comment: Thanks. BacktestTickerClass over-rides some methods of TickerClass, would that still work? Also, if Ticker is initially referenced to TickerClass, how can I just replace the definition when its being istantiated, is it because BacktestTickerCLass is a child of it?

Comment: Yes, you can declare the variable as parent class and instantiate as child class. But without casting, only methods of the parent class are available.

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance on the tickers

```
Public Class BaseTicker
    '...
End Class

Public Class DerivedTicker1
    Inherits BaseTicker
    '...
End Class

Public Class DerivedTicker2
    Inherits BaseTicker
    '...
End Class
```

Now you can define the ticker using the base ticker and assign it derived tickers

```
Public Class CoreEngine
    Public WithEvents Ticker As BaseTicker

    Public Sub New()
        Ticker  = New DerivedTicker1() 'Or possibly New BaseTicker()
    End Sub

    '...
End Class

Public Class ChildEngineClass
    Inherits CoreEngine

    'Do not redefine Ticker here.
    'Ticker is automatically inherited from the base class.

    Public Sub New()
        Ticker  = New DerivedTicker2()
    End Sub
End Class
```